# Dynamically render the Layout for a View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

AI have a web application developed using ASP.NET MVC which has a particular url, i.e, https://(myapp.com//ProductionLogs/GetTop25Logs which can be accessed by users without even logging in. I have two layouts 1.VANILLA and 2.CHOCO designed using Razor. I would like to display the VANILLA layout if a user who has not logged in, types the URL mentioned above and display the CHOCO layout for the user who had logged in.

But I am unable to achieve this. All the time, CHOCO layout is getting displayed Here's the code :

```
// Inside LogsController.cs
    public action GetTop25Logs()
    {            
        bool isPlainLayout = IfNotLoggedInShowVanillaLayout();
        ViewBag.PLAINLAYOUT = isPlainLayout;
        return View("Top25Logs");
    }
    public bool IfNotLoggedInShowVanillaLayout()
    {
        return !Request.IsAuthenticated;
    }

//Inside Top25Logs.cshtml
    @{
        if (ViewBag.PLAINLAYOUT)
        {    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutVANILLA.cshtml";}
        else
        {    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutCHOCO.cshtml";}
    }
```

Comment: why you are not using `Request.IsAuthenticated` to check whether the current request has been authenticated. what's exactly your problem

Comment: here's a nice article explaining many methods for doing this: http://www.dotnet-stuff.com/tutorials/aspnet-mvc/how-to-render-different-layout-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: My problem is all the time CHOCO layout is getting displayed

Comment: @esiprogrammer... Can you please elaborate on Request.IsAuthenticated? I am newbie to ASP.NET MVC...

Comment: @PrasathGovind take a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.isauthenticated(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I've deleted my answer as it's not your problem. You need to check your authentication code/debug the IfNotLoggedInShowVanillaLayout method

Comment: Hello... I have made some changes. The function is working fine. Can you please post your code on choosing the View Layout on the controller itself? Your code was neat.

Comment: Hello all, using Request.IsAuthenticated solved the issue. I am able to display the layout based on the validity of the authentication. I have now a doubt. Which approach is better and optimized? Selecting the layouts at the Controller  or selecting the layout at the View?